# Android Layout, how to make a radius and border like css

Tags: android, css, android-layout

I want to make some think like this in android layout background, is there any solution ?

**I have 2 borders, one at top and the other is bottom, and they have different colors, and also I don't want to have any borders at left and right**

CSS Code is:

```
#shape{
    border-radius :     2px;
    border-top :        1px solid #070709;
    border-bottom :     1px #383841;
    /*...*/
}
```

---

**NOTE: Border has radius too.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an XML in drawable folder and put this code in it:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#383841" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:top="3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

This layer list contains 3 items
1: color on top  with round corners.
2: color on bottom with round corners.
3: color on rest of the view.

You can set this as background to any view.